# jQuery "$(this)": is repeated use efficient?

Tags: jquery, performance

Is using $(this) repeatedly efficient or is it better to save it to a variable? I've seen it used repeatedly in a lot of jQuery code but since it is a call to the constructor I think it should be unnecessarily slow, am I wrong ?

Comment: It depends a bit on the amount. But basically it is better to declare a variable before.

Comment: It would be better to declare variable

Comment: This reminds me of two jQuery features that are often ignored: 1) Method calls can be chained 2) You can use all language features because it's just JavaScript

Comment: Not everything can be chained. Yes, many things can be done this way, but there are many cases where you could better work with variables (*think about scopes*). And I don't know how your second point is related to the question?! @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @eisbehr What I mean is that people tend to think of jQuery as a language/technology by itself (rather than a JavaScript library) that behaves like a kind of black box. I'm sure the OP wouldn't need to ask whether e.g. calling `Math.sqrt(2)` several times is more efficient than storing the result in a variable.

Comment: Ahh well, yes, you're right at this point. @ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun - a measurement. To see the difference you'd need to call `$(this)` tens of thousands times (depending on CPU).

The difference of *100,000* calls is roughly `100` vs. `70` milliseconds the `$(this)` being the slower one.

```js
var testCount = 100000;

$('div').each(function(){
  var self = $(this);
  
  // Measurement using $(this) selector
  var t1 = new Date();
  for (var i = 1; i <= testCount; i++){
   var nil = $(this).attr('id');
  }
  console.log('T1', (new Date()) - t1);
  
  // Measurement using saved declaration
  var t2 = new Date();
  for (var i = 1; i <= testCount; i++){
   var nil = self.attr('id');
  }
  console.log('T2', (new Date()) - t2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">  
</div>
```

Personally, I still use the saved declaration `var self = $(this)` since it's always a good habit to write more optimized code and also because of some possible confusions due to different contexts (as described in other answers).

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` will bring the DOM element, referenced by `this`, into a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/). So if often used, it will be done over and over again. Of course it is less effective then just using a varibale, once declared in an progress.

As `$()` is the constructor call of jQuery, everytime you use `$(this)`, a new instance will be generated and the job will be done again. Let's take a look at the jQuery source:

```
jQuery = function(selector, context) {
    return new jQuery.fn.init(selector, context);
};
```

There you see, that a new instance will be created with `new`. The lucky part is, that jQuery has not mutch to do, because `this` is already a DOM element and nearly ready to use.

Things would become worse, when you use string selectors in your script repeatly, e.g like `$('.my-element')`. There you should definitly use a variable, because jQuery has to do to many things on every construction then.

I'm not saying that `$(this)` is very slow. For one/two actions you will not need a variable. But it will never be as fast, as just doing it once!

Answer (score 1):

Only if you use `$(this)` let's say 10 times in an event callback, it can be reasonable to do something like

```
$('.my-elem').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.doSomething();
});
```

Needless to say: mind the scope! This will give you all sorts of problems:

```
var $this = $(this);

$('.my-elem').on('click', function() {
    $this.doSomething(); 
});

$('.other-elem').on('click', function() {
    $this.doSomething();
});
```

But don't worry too much about it. You'll never ever notice the speed difference, maybe if you use it in a loop that runs thousands of times... But it's always good to optimize code though.